# xQuery return dynamic value if element is empty

Tags: xml, datetime, xquery

**I'm having the following request message:**

```
<POORDERLIN>    
    <POLINESCHD>
        <DATETIME  qualifier="NEEDDELV"  type="T"  index="1">
            <YEAR>2022</YEAR>
            <MONTH>09</MONTH>
            <DAY>13</DAY>
            <HOUR>15</HOUR>
            <MINUTE>11</MINUTE>
            <SECOND>50</SECOND>
            <SUBSECOND>0000</SUBSECOND>
            <TIMEZONE>+0200</TIMEZONE>
        </DATETIME> 
    </POLINESCHD>
</POORDERLIN>
```

Sometimes this request message has empty year, month and day values. What I would like is when these elements are empty then fill in the current 'year', 'month' or 'day'.

**What I tried:**

```
  if data($POORDERLIN/POLINESCHD[1]/DATETIME/YEAR="") then (
   data($POORDERLIN/POLINESCHD[1]/DATETIME/YEAR="2022")
   )
   else ( 
     data($POORDERLIN/POLINESCHD[1]/DATETIME/YEAR)
   )
```

The problem with this method is that year is hardcoded and instead I would like to have a dynamic current year value. The same goes for 'month' and 'day'

How will I be able to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Which version of XQuery, which XQuery processor? And `data($POORDERLIN/POLINESCHD[1]/DATETIME/YEAR="2022")` returns the value of the comparison between the string literal `2022` and the `YEAR` element for which you already checked it is equal to the empty string so that complete expression will just return false.

Comment: I'm using xquery 1.0. I am working in an Oracle OSB environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the current year, month, and day from [`fn:current-date()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-current-date).

- [`year-from-date()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-year-from-date)
- [`month-from-date()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-month-from-date)
- [`day-from-date()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-day-from-date)

Though, not sure the example code you posted is going to do what you want. It will need to be adjusted to something more like:

```
if $POORDERLIN/POLINESCHD[1]/DATETIME/YEAR/data() then 
  $POORDERLIN/POLINESCHD[1]/DATETIME/YEAR/data()
else
  year-from-date(current-date())
```